# Run Sendria (MailTrap) in a Github workflow to test mail delivery in a WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, github-actions

I like to test the mail functionally from a WordPress plugin via a Github Workflow and [Sendria](https://github.com/msztolcman/sendria) (MailTrap)

This is my **working** workflow:

```yml
# Based on https://github.com/wp-cli/scaffold-command/blob/f9bad3dd7224d5684d950d31c486df70905e386f/templates/plugin-github.mustache
name: WordPress Test

on: [push]

env:
  WP_TESTS_DIR: /github/home/wp-tests/wordpress-tests-lib
  WP_CORE_DIR: /github/home/wp-tests/wordpress

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        php-version: [7.2]
        wordpress-version: [latest]
    container:
      image: junaidbhura/wp-tests:php-${{ matrix.php-version }}
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.27
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

    steps:

      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Install Composer dependencies
        run: |
          composer install --no-dev
          composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=6.1.0"
          composer global require "yoast/phpunit-polyfills=1.0.3"

      - name: Install WordPress test suite
        run: bash bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root root mysql ${{ matrix.wordpress-version }}

      - name: Tests
        run: $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit --config=phpunit-integration.xml
```

This workflow

- checkout my plugin
- install composer dependencies
- install the WordPress test suite
- run the Tests (which should contain mail tests)

Now I like to add [Sendria](https://github.com/msztolcman/sendria) to this flow by adding [this action](https://github.com/upgundecha/start-sendria-github-action) right above the first step:

```yml
  - name: Start Sendira
    uses: upgundecha/start-sendria-github-action@v1.0.0
    with:
      smtp-port: 1025
      http-port: 1080
```

To test that Sendria is running I check the endpoint via `curl` with an additional step:

```yml
  - name: Test
    run: |
      curl -LI http://127.0.0.1:1080
```

And this "Test" fails:

[image: Workflow view]

I tried the workflow locally with [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) where **this step worked** but have no idea how to get this working on Github.

I've also created a test repo on Github [here](https://github.com/evrpress/mail-test).

Comment: Could you try doing a `netstat -tulnp` command and getting results to check if Sendira is listening? And a `iptables -L` to see if anything blocks the port.

Comment: Also could you try with `localhost:1080`?

Comment: `localhost:1080` returns the same result and `netstat|iptables` not found (c 127)

Comment: Maybe there a two different docker containers which are not "connected"?